# How to use Spring Security in Spray routes?

Tags: spring, scala, spring-security, spray

I'm wondering whether or not it is possible to integrate [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) with [Spray](http://spray.io/) as a REST layer. I found examples with Play Framework, but I didn't manage to find anything for Spray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can. Just use [spray-servlet](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-servlet/) and configure Spring Security as usual.